# Copy or delete whole tuple from the list with specific item in tuple

Tags: python, list, tuples

I want to copy tuples from the list shown below having only a person as the first element of the tuple. How I can do it in efficient way to make it fast.

Also if is it possible to delete all tuples other than person it will also make it fast.

Input list is as below

```
[('person', '25.15', (515.781005859375, 380.65179443359375, 13.954371452331543, 24.346391677856445)), 
('bicycle', '25.47', (213.2113037109375, 459.51116943359375, 13.021369934082031, 27.720993041992188)), 
('person', '29.14', (247.71348571777344, 374.4739990234375, 45.45567321777344, 18.036327362060547))]
```

I want to get the resultant list as below

```
[('person', '25.15', (515.781005859375, 380.65179443359375, 13.954371452331543, 24.346391677856445)), 
('person', '29.14', (247.71348571777344, 374.4739990234375, 45.45567321777344, 18.036327362060547))]
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try `list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == "person", l))`?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your list is called `records`:

```
new_records = [record for record in records if record[0]=='person']
```

This is a compact way of writing:

```
new_records = []
for record in records:
    if record[0] == 'person':
        new_records.append(record)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using list comprehension should work

Try:

```
ip = [('person', '25.15', (515.781005859375, 380.65179443359375, 13.954371452331543, 24.346391677856445)),
('bicycle', '25.47', (213.2113037109375, 459.51116943359375, 13.021369934082031, 27.720993041992188)),
('person', '29.14', (247.71348571777344, 374.4739990234375, 45.45567321777344, 18.036327362060547))]


ip = [x for x in ip if x[0] == 'person']
print(ip)
```

**Output:**

```
[('person', '25.15', (515.781005859375, 380.65179443359375, 13.954371452331543, 24.346391677856445)), ('person', '29.14', (247.71348571777344, 374.4739990234375, 45.45567321777344, 18.036327362060547))]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
data = [('person', '25.15', (515.781005859375, 380.65179443359375, 13.954371452331543, 24.346391677856445)), 
('bicycle', '25.47', (213.2113037109375, 459.51116943359375, 13.021369934082031, 27.720993041992188)), 
('person', '29.14', (247.71348571777344, 374.4739990234375, 45.45567321777344, 18.036327362060547))]

data = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] == "person", data))

print(data)
```

I think it will give your desired output